# Why is this NaN

Tags: c++

Im trying to run the following code

```
  int salespersons=0,weeks=0,days=5;

  double weekly_sales[weeks][salespersons][days];
  double total_weekly_sales[weeks];


for(int w=0; w < weeks;w++)
  {
     for(int d =0; d < days; d++)
     {  

        for(int s=0; s < salespersons; s++)
        {

           {
              total_weekly_sales[w]+=weekly_sales[w][s][d];
              total_overall_weekly_sales[s]+= weekly_sales[w][s][d];

           }
        }  
     }

  }
```

when I run only..

```
cout << total_weekly_sales[0];
```

I get NaN therefore skipping the first section of the array while processing the rest.

Comment: Did you initialize the `total_weekly_sales` array?

Comment: Can you show us where you've initialized `total_weekly_ales` and `weekly_sales`?  Are you sure that none of those values are `NaN`?

Comment: Every time you assume in programming a kitten dies.

Comment: @BarışUşaklı that statement is misleading. are we supposed to assume more?

Comment: I'm trying to write a program that makes kittens die...

Comment: @DrewDormann I suggest you write [`i = i++ + ++i;`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
double weekly_sales[weeks][salespersons][days];
double total_weekly_sales[weeks];
```

***Uninitialized.***

Edit: this is how you should initialize them:

```
double weekly_sales[weeks][salespersons][days] = { { { 0.0 } } };
```

Comment: How would I initialize this properly. I further defined my question for clarity.

Comment: Hopefully just `= {0.0}` will work soon enough if the proposal goes well.

Comment: Just adding = { { { 0.0 } } }; makes it give the error "variable-sized object 'weekly_sales' may not be initialized"

Comment: I found that adding weekly_sales[0][0][0]=0;
    total_weekly_sales[0]=0;
makes it work

Comment: @Some guy: That is because the dimensions of the array are not constant. Change the line `int salespersons=0,weeks=0,days=5;` to `int const  salespersons=0,weeks=0,days=5;`

Answer (score 2):

```
double total_weekly_sales[weeks];

total_weekly_sales[w]+=weekly_sales[w][s][d];
```

You are adding to an uninitialized variable.

And printing an uninitialized variable

```
cout << total_weekly_sales[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You try with the code and you've initialized all variables

```
    int weeks=2,salepersons=3,days=1;

        double weekly_sales[weeks][salespersons][days];
          double total_weekly_sales[weeks];

    for(int w=0; w < weeks;w++)
      {
         for(int d =0; d < days; d++)
         {  
        for(int s=0; s < salespersons; s++)
        {

           {
              total_weekly_sales[w]=2;
              weekly_sales[w][s][d]=1;

           }
        }  
     }

  }


    for(int w=0; w < weeks;w++)
      {
         for(int d =0; d < days; d++)
         {  

            for(int s=0; s < salespersons; s++)
            {

               {
                  total_weekly_sales[w]+=weekly_sales[w][s][d];
                  total_overall_weekly_sales[s]+= weekly_sales[w][s][d];

               }
            }  
         }

      }
```

And use the library!!!